Parameters for facebook events
I use GTM to set every conversion tracking.
is it possible to set parameters like color, gender and size in array for events like add to cart, begin checkout and purchase for facebook pixel tracking ?
I want to be certain if it's correct to set those parameters

Yes, it is possible to pass parameters like color, gender, and size in an array for events like Add to Cart, Begin Checkout, and Purchase using Facebook Pixel through GTM. However, instead of sending each individual parameter separately, it’s best practice to use parent/child product structure for such scenarios.
By tracking the product ID or variant ID, which inherently includes attributes like color, size, and gender in its product data, you can simplify the tracking and keep it consistent. This way, you don’t need to send every parameter manually. Most eCommerce platforms or product management systems already associate attributes like color, size, and style with each product variant, so sending the product ID or variant ID is usually sufficient for tracking purposes.
If you still need to track individual attributes for reporting or analysis, you can pass these as custom parameters in your GTM data layer and configure the pixel to pick them up. But generally, the ID-based tracking is more efficient and aligns better with Facebook’s product catalog system.
